Is there a way to use Linear and Mixed Integer Programming to create groups while Minimizing the Average within the group in R?
I have a list of animals with their parents, that is used to calculate the relationship between them.
I am using the Rsymphony R package to generate matings where each female is crosses only once and each male is crossed twice. See bellow a reproducible example.
library("data.table")
library("Rsymphony")

Pedig = data.table(
  Indiv = as.character(c( 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 8,  9, 10, 11, 12)),
  Sire  = as.character(c(NA, NA, NA,  2,  1,  1, NA, 2,  2,  3,  3,  1)),
  Dam   = as.character(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  5,  5, 6,  7,  8, 10,  9)),
  Sex   = as.character(c( 1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2, 2,  2,  2,  2,  2))
)
Pedig[, Sex := data.table::fifelse(Sex =="1", "male", "female")]
pKin  <- matrix(
  c(
    0.500000,  0.0000,  0.000,  0.00000, 0.250000, 0.375000, 0.1250000, 0.1875000, 0.06250000, 0.09375000, 0.04687500, 0.28125000,
    0.000000,  0.5000,  0.000,  0.25000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.0000000, 0.2500000, 0.25000000, 0.12500000, 0.06250000, 0.12500000,
    0.000000,  0.0000,  0.500,  0.00000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.00000000, 0.25000000, 0.37500000, 0.00000000,
    0.000000,  0.2500,  0.000,  0.50000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.0000000, 0.1250000, 0.12500000, 0.06250000, 0.03125000, 0.06250000,
    0.250000,  0.0000,  0.000,  0.00000, 0.500000, 0.375000, 0.2500000, 0.1875000, 0.12500000, 0.09375000, 0.04687500, 0.18750000,
    0.375000,  0.0000,  0.000,  0.00000, 0.375000, 0.625000, 0.1875000, 0.3125000, 0.09375000, 0.15625000, 0.07812500, 0.23437500,
    0.125000,  0.0000,  0.000,  0.00000, 0.250000, 0.187500, 0.5000000, 0.0937500, 0.25000000, 0.04687500, 0.02343750, 0.18750000,
    0.187500,  0.2500,  0.000,  0.12500, 0.187500, 0.312500, 0.0937500, 0.5000000, 0.17187500, 0.25000000, 0.12500000, 0.17968750,
    0.062500,  0.2500,  0.000,  0.12500, 0.125000, 0.093750, 0.2500000, 0.1718750, 0.50000000, 0.08593750, 0.04296875, 0.28125000,
    0.093750,  0.1250,  0.250,  0.06250, 0.093750, 0.156250, 0.0468750, 0.2500000, 0.08593750, 0.50000000, 0.37500000, 0.08984375,
    0.046875,  0.0625,  0.375,  0.03125, 0.046875, 0.078125, 0.0234375, 0.1250000, 0.04296875, 0.37500000, 0.62500000, 0.04492188,
    0.281250,  0.1250,  0.000,  0.06250, 0.187500, 0.234375, 0.1875000, 0.1796875, 0.28125000, 0.08984375, 0.04492188, 0.53125000),
  nrow = 12
)

rownames(pKin) <- colnames(pKin) <- Pedig[["Indiv"]]

Kin  <- pKin[Pedig[Sex == "female"][["Indiv"]], Pedig[Sex == "male"][["Indiv"]]]
Zeros <- 0*Kin

rhsM <- rep(nrow(Kin)/ncol(Kin), ncol(Kin))
ConM <- NULL
for(k in 1:length(rhsM)){
  Con <- Zeros
  Con[, k] <- 1
  ConM <- rbind(ConM, c(Con))
}

rhsF <- rep(1, nrow(Kin))
ConF <- NULL
for(k in 1:length(rhsF)){
  Con <- Zeros
  Con[k, ] <- 1
  ConF <- rbind(ConF, c(Con))
}

A <- rbind(ConF, ConM)
RHS <- c(rhsF, rhsM)
ub.n <- 1
Bounds <- list(upper=list(ind=1:(length(rhsM)*length(rhsF)), val=rep(ub.n, length(rhsM)*length(rhsF))))
Dir <- rep("==", length(RHS))

# Rsymphony_solve_LP
res <- Rsymphony::Rsymphony_solve_LP(
  obj = c(Kin),
  mat = A,
  dir = Dir,
  rhs = RHS,
  bounds = Bounds,
  types = "I",
  max = FALSE
)
 
Solution <- matrix(res$solution, nrow=nrow(Zeros), ncol=ncol(Zeros))
Solution <- as.data.table(Solution)
colnames(Solution) <- colnames(Kin)
Solution[, ID1 := rownames(Kin)]
Solution <- melt(Solution, id.vars="ID1", variable.name="ID2", value.name="n", variable.factor = FALSE)
Solution <- Solution[n>0]
Solution[, Value := pKin[ID2, ID1], by = .I]

The solution to this simple example is shown below.
--------------------------------------
      ID1    ID2     n    Value
--------------------------------------
1:      9      1     1 0.062500
2:     11      1     1 0.046875
3:      5      2     1 0.000000
4:      7      2     1 0.000000
5:      8      3     1 0.000000
6:     12      3     1 0.000000
7:      6      4     1 0.000000
8:     10      4     1 0.062500
--------------------------------------

I am looking for a way to minimize the relationship of a Group instead of each pair of mating, in a way that the desired solution looks like the following table. In this case, I would like to provide the number of Groups (2) and the algorithm would create 2 groups with equal number of males and females. In this case, each group would have 2 males and 4 females.
------------------------------------------
         ID1     ID2       Value     Group
------------------------------------------
1:  9,11,5,7     1,2    0.027343         A
------------------------------------------
2: 8,12,6,10     3,4    0.015625         B
------------------------------------------

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thank you.

where and how did you install OptiSel? Did you install from a particular place, as the repo is missing?

I just realised that the OptiSel R package has been archived on CRAN (it can be installed from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/optiSel/).
So, I've added the values for the pKin matrix.

Please fix your code, it's not working.

The pKin matrix has been fixed.

Here's a solution using the ompr package for model formulation.
You want to minimize the relationships within a group. I believe this can be achieved by minimizing the difference between groups. Therefore, to achieve your desired result, I am minimizing the mating pair relationship values and the difference in sum of relationship values between groups.
See code comments below for model explanations. Note that I have redefined the male and female IDs to increment from 1 to keep the code simple. I am using glpk solver but you can use any you want.
library(dplyr)
library(ROI)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
# library(ROI.plugin.symphony)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)    

n_males <- 4
n_females <- 8
n_groups <- 2
males_per_group <- n_males / n_groups

# for 4 males and 8 females, pKin matrix should be 4x8
# assuming rows 1:4 represent the 4 males and columns 5:12 represent the 8 females
pKin <- pKin[1:4, 5:12]

pKin_df <- data.frame(
    m = c(t(row(pKin))),
    f = c(t(col(pKin))),
    pKin_value = c(t(pKin))
)

# model variables
# x[m, f, g] = 1 if male m and female f are paired and assigned to group g else 0
# y[m, g] = 1 if male m is assigned to group g else 0
# slack[g] = pKin difference between group 1 and other groups
# max_slack = max pKin difference between group 1 and other groups

model <- MIPModel() %>% 
    add_variable(x[m, f, g], m = 1:n_males, f = 1:n_females, g = 1:n_groups, type = "binary") %>% 
    add_variable(y[m, g], m = 1:n_males, g = 1:n_groups, type = "binary") %>% 
    add_variable(slack[g], g = 1:n_groups, type = "continuous", lb = 0) %>% 
    add_variable(max_slack, type = 'continuous', lb = 0) %>% 
    add_constraint(
        # males can/must mate with 2 females
        sum_over(x[m, f, g], f = 1:n_females, g = 1:n_groups) == 2, m = 1:n_males
    ) %>% 
    add_constraint(
        # females can/must mate with only 1 male
        sum_over(x[m, f, g], m = 1:n_males, g = 1:n_groups) == 1, f = 1:n_females
    ) %>% 
    add_constraint(
        # m-f pair can belong to a group only if m assigned to that group
        x[m, f, g] <= y[m, g], m = 1:n_males, f = 1:n_females, g = 1:n_groups
    ) %>% 
    add_constraint(
        # each male can belong to only 1 group
        sum_over(y[m, g], g = 1:n_groups) == 1, m = 1:n_males
    ) %>% 
    add_constraint(
        # max males per group
        sum_over(y[m, g], m = 1:n_males) == males_per_group, g = 1:n_groups
    ) %>% 
    add_constraint(
        # minimize relationships within group
        sum_over(x[m, f, 1] * pKin[m, f], m = 1:n_males, f = 1:n_females) + slack[g] == sum_over(x[m, f, g] * pKin[m, f], m = 1:n_males, f = 1:n_females),
        g = 2:n_groups
    ) %>%
    add_constraint(
        # get max slack[g]
        slack[g] <= max_slack, g = 1:n_groups
    ) %>% 
    set_objective(
        sum_over(x[m, f, g] * pKin[m, f], m = 1:n_males, f = 1:n_females, g = 1:n_groups) + max_slack,
        sense = "min"
    )

result <- model %>% 
    solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk"))

result %>% 
    get_solution(x[m, f, g]) %>% 
    filter(value == 1) %>% 
    select(-value) %>% 
    arrange(m) %>% 
    left_join(pKin_df, by = c('m', 'f')) %>% 
    group_by(group = g) %>% 
    summarise(
        males = toString(unique(m)),
        females = toString(unique(f)),
        pKin_value = mean(pKin_value)
    )

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  group males females    pKin_value
  <int> <chr> <chr>           <dbl>
1     1 3, 4  4, 8, 1, 6     0.0156
2     2 1, 2  5, 7, 2, 3     0.0273


Thanks for the answer. I wonder why did you put the constraints where males can mate to 2 females only females can mate to 1 male only? The idea is that a male can mate to any of the 4 females in that group (4 possibilities) and a female with the 2 males. Think about a mass mating where all females can mate with all males. Could you describe a little bit more about the reasons for these 2 constraints?

In addition, why the constraint that minimizes the relationship within group is only between group 1 and the others? If there are more than 2 groups, this constraint should be take into account all pairs of groups.

I put mating constraints since your problem statement mentions "each female is crosses only once and each male is crossed twice". You can remove/modify these constraints as per your needs.

Regarding relationships within groups - Assume 3 groups and relationship value within nth group is r_n; my thinking is that the relationship within groups can be minimized by equalizing relationships across each group. Of course such equality may not be possible based on data so we have to introduce a slack variable. Then, r_1 + slack_2 = r_2 and r_1 + slack_3 = r_3. This is following the logic if a = b and a = c then b = c. Thus, relationships within each group is minimized by equalizing relationships across each group without needing a constraint for each pair of groups.
